# Why is the request not covered by signature custom binding?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding, xml-signature

What I am trying to achieve is custom binding that supports a signatured header.

I create a custom binding in the following steps:

1. I create three elements to setup the custom binding:
   SecurityBindingElement, TextMessageEncodingElement, HttpsTransportBindingElement.

   ```
   private BindingElement CreateSecurityBindingElement()
   {
       SecurityBindingElement security = SecurityBindingElement.CreateCertificateOverTransportBindingElement();
       security.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10;
       security.SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.LaxTimestampLast;
       security.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic128Sha256Rsa15;
       X509SecurityTokenParameters X509Parameters = new X509SecurityTokenParameters();
       X509Parameters.InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.Once;
       X509Parameters.RequireDerivedKeys = false;
       X509Parameters.X509ReferenceStyle = X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.SubjectKeyIdentifier;
       security.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.Signed.Add(X509Parameters);
       security.IncludeTimestamp = true;
       security.EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;
       return security;
   }

   private static BindingElement CreateTextMessageEncodingElement()
   {
       BindingElement encoding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement
       {
           MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap11WSAddressing10,
       };
       return encoding;
   }

   private BindingElement CreateTransportBindingElement()
   {
       BindingElement transport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement
       {
           RequireClientCertificate = true,
       };
       return transport;
   }
   ```
2. Then I create the custom binding as follows:

   ```
   private Binding CreateBinding()
   {
       BindingElement security = CreateSecurityBindingElement1();
       BindingElement encoding = CreateTextMessageEncodingElement();
       BindingElement transport = CreateTransportBindingElement();
       return new CustomBinding(
           encoding,
           security,
           transport
       );
   }
   ```
3. After that I create a ChannelFactory with the binding

   ```
   public TResponse Send<TResponse>(Guid messageId, Func<TChannel, TResponse> send)
   {
       OperationContext context = new OperationContext((IContextChannel)Channel);
       using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(context))
       {
           var address = new EndpointAddress("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous?oin=00000001800866472000");
           context.OutgoingMessageHeaders.ReplyTo = address;
           context.OutgoingMessageHeaders.From = address;
           context.OutgoingMessageHeaders.MessageId = new UniqueId(messageId);
           return send(Channel);
       }
   }
   ```

When I try to send the message it ends in a FaultException with the message 'XPath expression //*[local-name()='To' and namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing']|//*[local-name()='From' and namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing']|//*[local-name()='Action' and namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing']|//*[local-name()='MessageID' and namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing']|//*[local-name()='Body' and namespace-uri()='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'] not covered by signature (from client)'

I can't figure out why the message is not signed. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Did you work it out? We're facing the same issue.